# JavaFX: Offsetting Polygon/Polyline position

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, shapes

I am trying to create a shape with some extra space above it, but it seems like all I have is `getPoints()` to play with. I thought I could do a position offset by providing `getPoints()` with offset of the `double` values.

What I found out:

```
0 0 20 0 20 20 0 20
```

is equals to

```
-10 -10 10 -10 10 10 -10 10
```

and equals to

```
100 100 120 100 120 120 100 120
```

All of them give me the same 20 x 20 pixels square, without any space around it.

Is there any quick and reliable way to offset the position of a `Polygon` or `Polyline`?

Comment: Pane class can be used for absolute co-ordinates.

Comment: @RajuDangol Thanks. That certainly looks like a feasible way to do it. Didn't notice that function until I read Javadoc for `Pane` class. :)